# codeigniter - convert html to pdf

Tags: html, codeigniter, pdf, converters

I have a little problem. I have html page and I want to convert to pdf. My index page has a list that will get to the database and click on "Download PDF", I put this list in a PDF file.

**My controller:**

```
<?php

    class pdf_c extends CI_Controller{
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('url', 'mediatutorialpdf'));
        }

    function index($download_pdf = ''){
           $ret = '';
           $ID = 1;
           $pdf_filename = 'user_info_'.$ID.'.pdf';
           $link_download = ($download_pdf == TRUE)?'':anchor(base_url().'index.php/true', 'Download PDF');
           $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `ci_pdf_user` WHERE `id` = '{$ID}' LIMIT 1");
           if($query->num_rows() > 0)
           {
                $user_info = $query->row_array();
           }

           $data_header = array(
                'title' => 'Convert codeigniter to pdf'
           );
           $data_userinfo = array(
                'user_info' => $user_info,
                'link_download' => $link_download
           );
           $header = $this->load->view('header',$data_header, true);
           $user_info = $this->load->view('user_table', $data_userinfo, true);
           $footer = $this->load->view('footer','', true);

           $output = $header.$user_info.$footer;
           if($download_pdf == TRUE)
           {
                generate_pdf($output, $pdf_filename);
           }
           else
           {
                echo $output;
           }
      }
}
?>
```

The problem is when I click the button "Download PDF" should redirect me to the function index () and get the $ download_pdf = true. And so called generate_pdf function () that will generate the PDF.

I think the problem is in the variable $ link_download, but can not solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could try with:

```
function index(pdf = 0)...
```

Then check that optional parameter with:

$`pdf = $this->uri->segment(2, 0);` //not sure, should be 2? try it...`

And then, `if $pdf=='1' (send nummber rather than string 'true') ...etc,etc...`

Comment: thanks. I managed to solve the problem. Was in the function call. Was thus:

`$link_download = (site_url().'/pdf_c/index/1');`